# Enclosing a rectangular area...calculus question?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, area

I have some calculus question that I need help solving.

Like good gardeners, we would like to enclose a rectangular garden with 3000 m of fence which we have available. We would like to have a rectangular fencing, which is divided into three parts like the picture below. What is the biggest surface, that we can enclose in this way?

This is what I had already done ( picture bellow ) and I found that x=375; maximum of the function. But I am not sure if that is the right result.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

All is well......................

Comment: Therefor the result of this assigment aka the biggest surface, that we can enclose in this way is 375 sq m?

Comment: No, you have calculated the $x$ dimension that maximizes the area.  You need to plug that into your equation for $S(x)$ to find the area.

Comment: Okey, did that. And the result is S=281250 ...so the bigest area we can enclose is 281250 sq m?

Comment: That is what I get.